# How to kill a process in C when pid is know

Tags: c, kill, pid

I have a cleanup process which needs to kill the process whose PID is passed as an argument to it.

I can very well use the `kill(pid_t, SIGKILL)` to kill it. However the PID which i get is an integer value. So i cant get a pid_t out of it. Is there any way to use and integer pid to kill the process?

Well. I can very well use `system("kill -9 <pid>");`

I am looking for a solution from C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did the PID get into an integer type in the first place? If your function takes a PID, it should take it as a `pid_t`. If it's a text argument, you should parse it into a `pid_t`, not an `int`.

Unless you have some unusual situation, the only integer-like variable you should ever store a PID in is a `pid_t`.

Comment: `pid_t` is a signed integer type, so it's certainly valid to store pids in `intmax_t`. In practice, it's fine to store them in plain `int` too. It's likely that the only reason `pid_t` was even invented is because some ugly legacy systems used `short` for pids, while newer systems wanted to use `int`, and therefore `pid_t` was invented for use in the prototypes so that each system could define `pid_t` as `short` or `int` (or, unlikely, something else) as desired.

Comment: So far as I know, there is no requirement that `pid_t` be a signed integer type. (Do you have a citation?) It is only required that `(pid_t)-1` and `(pid_t)0` work and don't overlap legitimate PIDs. This can certainly be done with unsigned integer types (as many systems do with `time_t`), and it certainly works with floating point types as well.

Comment: "blksize_t, pid_t, and ssize_t shall be signed integer types." Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html

Comment: Wow, I looked there and missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`pid_t` is actually an integer!

See http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_566.html

Answer (score 1):

The `pid_t` is a signed integer. See [libc](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_566.html). Just use the integer value as the first argument in `kill`

Answer (score 1):

pid_t is a data type defined in `types.h`. It is a signed integer type only.

Did you try directly assigning your integer to pid_t variable? Is it not working?